# using jQuery how to catch id value within the table

Tags: jquery

Here I'm using jQuery table please help me. How can I catch Id value and bind this value to next function

```
success: function (data) {
  var $table = $('<table></table>').addClass('table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered');
  var $header = $('<thead><tr><th>EmpId</th><th>EmpName</th><th>Email</th><th>Action</th></tr><thead/>');
  $table.append($header);
  $.each(data, function (i, value) {
    var $row = $('<tr></tr>');
    $row.append($('<td/>').html(value.Emp_Id));                 
    $row.append($('<td/>').html('<a id="Hello" href="#" value='+value.Emp_Id+'>Edit</a>'))
    $table.append($row);
  });
  $('#Div1').html($table);
}
```

Here I want to bind that value-

```
$('body').on('click', '#Hello', function (e) {
  var page2 = $(this).valueOf();
  console.log(page2);    
});
```

Comment: `how can i catch Id value`->which id value you are talking about?

Comment: within a  row wen i click on edit Link its value should bind

Comment: Are you trying to get value of `#Hello`?

Comment: Yes @phaniKumar

Comment: its comming as   http://localhost:44516/ApiProject/Home_Stored/HomePage.html?value=100    but i need to bind value to its next function

Comment: Since each table row is having `Edit` link, suggest you to change `id=Hello` to `class=Hello`. As there should be unique id for every element in DOM. Change `$('body').on('click', '#Hello', function (e) {` to `$('body').on('click', '.Hello', function (e) {` and then use `$(this).attr('value');`

Comment: no use @phaniKumarM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  need to do it like below:-

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr td a', function (e) { //bind click on link
    e.preventDefault(); //stop page refresh and page url change
    var page2 = $(this).attr('value'); //get link value
    console.log(page2);
});
```

Working Example:-

```js
$(function(){
var data=[{Emp_Id:1,Emp_Name:'alive',Email:'alive@gmail.com'},{Emp_Id:2,Emp_Name:'to',Email:'to@gmail.com'},{Emp_Id:3,Emp_Name:'die',Email:'die@gmail.com'}];
var $table = $('<table></table>').addClass('table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered');
    var $header = $('<thead><tr><th>EmpId</th><th>EmpName</th><th>Email</th><th>Action</th></tr><thead/>');
    $table.append($header);
    $.each(data, function (i, value) {
        var $row = $('<tr></tr>');
        $row.append($('<td/>').html(value.Emp_Id));
        $row.append($('<td/>').html(value.Emp_Name));
        $row.append($('<td/>').html(value.Email));
        $row.append($('<td/>').html('<a href="#" value='+value.Emp_Id+'>Edit</a>')); // no need of creating repetitive id="Hello"
    
        $table.append($row);
    });
    $('#Div1').html($table);
    
})
$(document).on('click', 'tr td a', function (e) { //bind click on link
    e.preventDefault(); //stop page refresh and page url change
    var page2 = $(this).attr('value'); //get link value
    console.log(page2);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Div1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using id="Hello" create onclick function in a-tag itself.

use this code within your success function

```js
$(function(){
var data=[{Emp_Id:1},{Emp_Id:2},{Emp_Id:3}];
var $table = $('<table></table>').addClass('table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered');
    var $header = $('<thead><tr><th>EmpId</th><th>EmpName</th><th>Email</th><th>Action</th></tr><thead/>');
    $table.append($header);
    $.each(data, function (i, value) {
        var $row = $('<tr></tr>');
        $row.append($('<td/>').html(value.Emp_Id));                 
        $row.append($('<td/>').html('<a  href="#" onclick="editEmployee('+value.Emp_Id+')">Edit</a>'))
        $table.append($row);
    });
    $('#Div1').html($table);
    
})
function editEmployee(id){
   console.log(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Div1"></div>
```

Comment: change this $row.append($('<td/>').html('<a  href="#" onclick="editEmployee('+value.Emp_Id+')">Edit</a>'))   and add this function function editEmployee(id){
   console.log(id);
}

Comment: Even though same result @kalaiselva

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157333/discussion-between-kalaiselvan-a-and-md-mohi).